# Mathematica Lookup Tables

Tags: arrays, wolfram-mathematica, lookup-tables

I am making a mathematical model which requires 3 input parameters (as floats) - let's say j,j0 and j1. 'j0' is the primary variable; for each j0 there are multiple j values. For each j there are multiple j1 values. Therefore, I use nested 'do' loops to generate my data.

```
Do[
Do[
Do[

(*some functions here*)

,{j1,j1Start,j1End,angleIncrement}](*Close the j1 'do' loop.*),
{j,jStart,jEnd,angleIncrement}](*Close the j 'do' loop.*),
{j0,j0Start, j0End,angleIncrement}(*Close the j0 'do' loop.*)]
```

Now my model has become quite large, so I've tried to create 'lookup tables' of results. There are a lot of results. For each of the (dozens) of functions I've written, I must loop through (as shown above), do some calculations, and record the results corresponding to each particular combination of input j0,j,j1 values.(The input parameters are not integers, are not necessarily evenly spaced and the results certainly are not either.)

The 'lookup tables' I've made are essentially arrays:

```
arrayname[inputVar1a,inputVar2a,inputVar3a] = {result1a,result2a}
arrayname[inputVar1b,inputVar2b,inputVar3b] = {result1b,result2b} etc.
```

In reality, the 3 input parameters were input to functions, and the results were appended to the array - removing the requirement to use the functions again.

I'm finding however, that Mathematica doesn't like what I'm doing (or how I'm doing it.) Here's a piece of code showing what I've been doing:

```
  Do[(*Initialise the j0 'do' loop.*)
 Do[(*Initialise the j 'do' loop.*)
  Do[(*Initialise the j1 'do' loop.*)

   entryPoint[j0, j, j1] = {}(*Initialise the array.*);

   If[j == 270,

    AppendTo[
      entryPoint[j0, j, j1],(*Result of other function here*)] &&
     AppendTo[entryPoint[j0, j, j1],(*Result of other function here*)]

    ](*Close the'if' loop.*),

   {j1, zMaxMinResults[j0, j][[1]], zMaxMinResults[j0, j][[2]], 
    zAngleIncrement [j0, j][[1]]}(*Loop across j1.*)
   ](*Close the j1 'do' loop.*),

  {j, jStart, jEnd, angleIncrement}(*Loop across j.*)
  ](*Close the j 'do' loop.*),

 {j0, j0Start, j0End, angleIncrement}(*Loop across j0.*)
 ](*Close the j0 'do' loop.*)
```

When I want to call a result then, I use Part[expr,i] or [[i]] as follows.
Here's some data (with only 2 input parameters rather than 3).

```
zMaxMinResults[22.5,319.]={-49.711,-49.}

zMaxMinResults[22.5,319.5]={-50.211,-49.5}

zMaxMinResults[22.5,320.]={-50.711,-50.}

zMaxMinResults[22.5,320.5]={-51.211,-50.5}

zMaxMinResults[22.5,321.]={-51.711,-51.}

zMaxMinResults[22.5,321.5]={-52.211,-51.5}
```

And here's how I reference it.

```
In[102]:=
zMaxMinResults[22.5, 319.]
zMaxMinResults[22.5, 319.][[1]]
Part[zMaxMinResults[22.5, 319.], 1]
zMaxMinResults[22.5, 319.][[2]]
Part[zMaxMinResults[22.5, 319.], 2]


    Out[102]= {-49.711, -49.}

    Out[103]= -49.711

    Out[104]= -49.711

    Out[105]= -49.

    Out[106]= -49.
```

However, usually, the referencing code, [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkbcD.jpg)] etc., returns the 1st, 2nd or 3rd input parameter. For example.

```
x2[22.5,167.,102.371]={2908.02,5892.49}

In[119]:=
x2[22.5, 319., 102.371]
x2[22.5, 319., 102.371][[1]]
Part[x2[22.5, 319., 102.371], 1]
x2[22.5, 319., 102.371][[2]]
Part[x2[22.5, 319., 102.371], 2]


Out[119]= x2[22.5, 319., 102.371]

Out[120]= 22.5

Out[121]= 22.5

Out[122]= 319.

Out[123]= 319.
```

You'll see that the code returns the incorrect figure - the input variables' value. Finally, here's a separate piece of code which exhibits the same sort behaviour.

I'm that I shouldn't be generating or filling arrays in this fashion and any assistance here is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: using floating point numbers for indices is problematic because for numerical reasons you can have values that are nearly the same and display the same, but since they differ by some small amount they do not match your index.  Try multiplying all the `j` values by 10 so you are working with integers.

Answer (score 0):

Illustrating what I said in comment, I suspect you are seeing something like this:

```
 Clear[g];
 i = 0.; Do[  g[i] = i ; i += .01  , { 101}]
 {g[0.], g[.1], g[.5], g[1.]}
```

> {0., 0.1, g[0.5], g[1.]}

The problem here is the value "0.01" cannot be exactly represented in binary, so you have an error accumulation. The last `g` index assigned  is actually:

```
 g[1.0000000000000007`]
```

> 1.

One fix is to do something like this:

```
 Clear[g];
 i = 0.; Do[  g[i] = i ; i = Round[i + .01, .01]  , { 101}]
 {g[0.], g[.1], g[.5], g[1.]}
```

> {0., 0.1, 0.5, 1.}

alternately in mathematica if you use floating point do loop incrementation that rounding is done for you, so this works:

```
 Clear[g];
 Do[  g[i] = i , { i, 0, 1, .01}]
 {g[0.], g[.1], g[.5], g[1.]}
```

> {0., 0.1, 0.5, 1.}

Note that the same issue will arise if you are arriving at your indices through some calculation, so Its best not to do this.